# How to access the registry with date field?

Tags: visual-c++

I am a beginner to MFC VC++ . I am working on the project which is a trail version. It should run on system for 60 days trail period. I have to use the system registry to create a key with the installed date. Every time the user runs the software I have to match the installed date with current and show the remaining days the software could be used.

Comment: Beginner for MFC eh? Quit fast! While you can still be rescued from that mess!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the windows API functions to read/write from the registry:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx

Particularly you will need [RegCreateKeyEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [RegSetValueEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [RegGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

That being said. I would seriously consider using a third party, tried and tested, licensing solution as opposed to rolling your own.  If you are just writing a registry key and setting the date in it, then it will be very easy to hack your software. All one needs do is monitor the registry to find the values being written and then change them. You also need to take into account someone rolling the clock back to gain more time. A quick google search yielded several options. I do not have one I can recommend, just wanted to suggest that you consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,But I don't understand that why you want to store the "Install_date" in new key.It is already store in the registry.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{......}\

From here you can use these registry............